# How to manage Whatsapp Scroll View Logic (Android)

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-studio, layout

I try to create a layout with scrol view inside a scrol view how Whatssupp works 
here is how my layout looks like
[image]

When I scroll up "number One part" should dissapear and "number two" with its lisview should should take Number Ones place but TOPICS Should remain at the top of the screen. Very Familiar as Whatssupp. The examples that I found doesnt fix my problem. Hope to receive any help. Thank you.

and here is my xml codes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <!-- Main Container -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--Following  Followers Part 1 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_leftside_layout_2_followers"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:text="554 Followers" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:src="@drawable/person_icon" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_leftside_layout_2_following"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:text="654 Following" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/txt_frag_followers_following"
            android:textSize="35dp" />
        <!--TOPICS Part 2 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="@color/grey_200"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some Button" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some Button" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some Button" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some Button" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some Button" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some Button" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some Button" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some Button" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some Button" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some Button" />


            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lv_leftside_layout_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </ListView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

the xml style you are following is not good for future use. because all are fixed/static view elements 
you can try the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">



            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dip"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:titleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.Title"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                >

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabGravity="center"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dip"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/NavigationTabTextAppeareance"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white" />



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:background="@color/semiwhite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

for view pager adapter you can set whatever data you want

Comment: Thanks for advice, I am not accustomed with the structure you recomend but second part for application will be improvement in this kind of structures, we need just main frame.

Comment: okay, then try using 
           `android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"` for first and second parts and hide first part in onScroll

Comment: Shouldnt I need to use some Scroll View, I hoped to receive this info suggestion from answers